# FrameSet and HTML5 Video on iPad / iPhone - Video breaks out of frame?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, html5-video

I'm using an HTML5 `<video>` player on a page that is displayed withing a `frame`. My player breaks out of the frame and is visible on top of the other frames. **Any ways of fixing this issue?**

I've made a "screenshot" of the problem:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `frame` element is [no longer valid in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features). The recommendation is to use the `iframe` element instead. If you must.